# How to have a video player resume from where I last left off?

Tags: bash, video, vlc, scripts

I'd like to be able to launch a video player (VLC, SMPlayer) via Terminal, using some command like `resume_media` and then it will automatically find the most recently played media file (.mkv, mp4 etc.) in a folder and resume the playback from where it was stopped.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Tim: No, that question is totally different from this one. That one talks about resuming playback in a *particular video file*, but this one is about finding the most recently played video file, and *then* resume from where playback was stopped.

Comment: Cool, undone that! Hmm you could possibly write a script for that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Zeitgeist daemon running on your system, it should save some helpful info to ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel file. Zeitgeist monitors access to files on disk, so it should know your most recently played video file. Unfortunately the files are not sorted by file access, but the database contains that information too, so you can grep all data you need and then look for most recently file in a loop.

I just wrote a Bash script to find the most recently played file with "video/*" MIME type and play it using SMPlayer (but you can use any video player, of course).

```
#!/bin/bash

date_recent=""
file_name=""
# get list of files with MIME type "video/*"
video_files_list=$(grep -B3 "<mime:mime-type type=\"video/" ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel | grep "modified=")

while read -r line
do
    # extract modification time (last access to file)
    date_line=$(echo "$line" | cut -d'"' -f6)
    if [ "$date_recent" \< "$date_line" ]
    then
        date_recent=$date_line  
        file_name=$(echo "$line" | cut -d'"' -f2)
    fi
done <<< "$video_files_list"

# file name is encoded like URL, use Python to decode it
file_name=$(python -c "import sys, urllib as ul; print ul.unquote_plus(\"$file_name\")")

# play video
smplayer "$file_name"
```

Save it to file, add permission to execute and it should work.